# nullreferenceexception when trying to update text in a label, and working with threads

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    Thread timeThread = new Thread(timeKeeper);
    private static int min = 0, sec = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected void startstop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timeThread.Start();
        if(timer.IsRunning()) {timer.Stop}
        else timer.Start();
    }
    private static void timeKeeper()
    {
        while (timer.IsRunning)
        {
            mydelegate();
        }
    }
    private static void mydelegate()
    {
        _Default temp = new _Default();
        temp.Update();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        min = timer.Elapsed.Minutes;
        sec = timer.Elapsed.Seconds;
        time.Text = min + ":" + sec;
    }
}
```

what i want to do is have a button that controls the a stopwatch, when you click it it starts, click it again it stops. I figured the best way to do it is with a thread if i want the time.text display to continue update and to be able to click the button still. when i run the above program it gets to time.text = min + ":" + sec; and throws a nullreferenceexception. Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. I am semi new to programming in C#/asp.net.

Is there a better way of working with delegates then this. I have spent hours looking up how to use them with not many usual/easy to understand tutorials or blogs

Comment: Make sure your `time` variable (which I guess is your label) is properly created.

Comment: Where are you defining `time`?

Comment: sorry, i should have mentioned i am using vs10, so the label was created from the design side of the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where to begin.

Remember you are programming a webpage, and every call to a server result in a new webpage life cycle on the server. So using threads in a webpage will not result in the correct behaviour.

To get the kind of behaviour you want, you'll have to do the timer and click handling on the client instead of the server. You can use jQuery to facilitate in this. One other option is to use ajax if you have to keep the server up-to-date.

Comment: i was originally trying to use a timer and click handling, but ran into more trouble then it was worth. i will continue to learn more about it though and will eventually have to revert back to it. I just wanted to get opinions on the matter so i can learn more. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is here:

```
_Default temp = new _Default();
```

The new class isn't passing through the ASP.Net pipeline, so when you try to update a control in the markup (*time*), it has not actually loaded.

I think your approach here is a bit flawed.  If you want to do it on the server side, you'll need to use repeated Ajax requests (or a web socket) to keep the browser in sync with the timer object on the server.  Not to mention, what happens when you have multiple users and the threads start colliding?  It seems like it would be far better to use Javascript.

Comment: like i said i am semi new to coding with c#/asp.net, im not good with javascript or ajax. i am willing to learn if i have to but i would like to stick with what i already have a basic knowledge of. thank you for your first comment though

Comment: @BrandonWentworth if you want to work with .Net instead of Javascript, consider making a Silverlight application.  Doing this with Asp.Net just isn't the right approach.